# What is the most simplest way to change (fix) the colors in the terminal (bash)

Tags: bash

Just installed elementary os. in the terminal, ll gives a list of files and directories showing directories with lightblue color with green background - which is unlucky with respect to contrast, hardly can read anything. also this looks screaming.

What is the most simple way to change this theme? I installed dconf Editor and believe I could set a custom value for

#073642:#dc322f:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#ec0048:#2aa198:#94a3a5:#586e75:#cb4b16:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#d33682:#2aa198:#6c71c4

Just do not know where to get more reasonable values for that. And not sure if this is the right point too.

Answer (score 1):

Try Elementary Tweaks, as described here (https://itsfoss.com/install-elementary-tweaks-in-elementary-os-freya-luna/). It will appear in `Settings` panel.

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks good, but unfortunately the 3rd command for installation gives an error: sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks -° Unable to locate elementary-weaks

Comment: looks like tweaks are not maintained no more: https://superuser.com/questions/823691/elementaryos-not-able-to-install-apps-through-ppa

Comment: this allows changing background color, not the problem of the colors in the terminal, like green-blue letters with green background for folders - making them perfectly unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, you can use the following command.

`gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings background '#090921111a1b'`

The Hash #090921111a1b is broken down to #RRRRGGGGBBBB in base16 0-f

When you have what color you like, place the command in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Thank you, I tweaked some gsettings already and your answer is generally right. I wanted to change the theme not only the background however. A big problem is the crying color of folders that makes them unreadable instead of highlighting them.

Answer (score 0):

Was headbutting this problem as well just now. Same deal, just installed Elementary OS and some of the Directories had Blue text on Green background. Although, I seem to have the same issue on my Ubuntu Server which I most often connect to through Putty witch seems to override the colors.

I found that the problem lies within bash, or at least a simple solution lies in bash. In your home folder, edit the file ".bashrc"

Add these two lines at the end of the file.

`LS_COLORS='ow=0;40:di=1;36:';
export LS_COLORS`

Then run command "source .bashrc"
You could also play with the values for 0;40 and 1;36. As I understand it "di=" sets the color for your normal directories, while "ow=" seems to set the colors for directories where non-owners lack write permission.

This guide had some useful info on setting the bash-colors.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console